# Loadrunner higher response time due to adding of products in cart

Tags: performance, loadrunner

I am facing an issue in my web application performance testing.A test script is executed for a particular scenario (where my application is ecommerce web application) which handles the products in the shopping bag.This adding of products in the wishlist of particular user profile causes high response time for that transaction.Now i would like to have only few products in the user cart wishlist and remove the remaining items from cart which may reduce the response time.

How can i remove products using c code in the LR script?
Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Catch the request which removes the items from the cart by using developer tools in the browser or Fiddler. 

Once the request is traced, create a web_custom_request(); with the item data. Make sure that you have added the relevant headers before that custom request.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered recording the user actions with LoadRunner related to removing items from the cart and then implementing such actions in your code?

I have no idea why Fiddler is recommended for recording when LoadRunner has two built in recording capabilities for web virtual users.  One is a sockets based recording.  The other is a fiddler based proxy recorder.   So, to use Fiddler when Fiddler is built in seems goofy to say the least.

And yes, larger carts will degrade.  I am reminded of a client I worked with some time ago.  They had a monitoring script for their ecommerce site which woke up every five to ten minutes, signed into an account, added an element to the cart, timed all of the actions, then exited.   Notice what is missing?  Removing the element from the cart.

Over time the cart grew to thousands upon thousands of items in the cart, then it reached a tipping point.   The tipping point is when the Java Virtual Machine switched to a stop-the-world garbage collection to remove the now hundreds of thousands of objects in the cart from memory.   This impacted then entire site.   All of this was related to using immature resources to build the monitoring scripts and their failure to recognize that you needed to leave the application in the same start as when you arrived in order to achieve a common sampling basis.

And yes, the cart performance for that one user was degrading as well. Programming/Engineering resources were chasing the reason why.  Until the account cart size was investigated no one knew that they were chasing an engineering ghost.  The dollars spent chasing the ghost easily offset any savings from using a less mature resource to build the monitoring script.  Lesson learned...painfully...

Comment: I have the experience that few requests are not being captured in LoadRunner, though LR is built on Fiddler engine for recording. In that case, I use browser developer tool or Fiddler.

Comment: "t few requests are not being captured in LoadRunner, "   I have no such experience (for web) and I have been using LoadRunner continuously since April1996 and version 4.51

Comment: I recently tested ReactJS web application where few API calls not captured by LoadRunner. I used Chrome Dev Tool to trace that request.

Comment: React is a view layer only framework.   This is different than angular which is a complete framework governing end user interface and server side communications.  I suspect something else was at play in your app generating a dynamically constructed request in Javascript.  This request would change based upon data used.   A tool, Loadrunner or any other, does not simply drop a request put over the same interface as every other request which has been collected.